# Django 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_app''

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have been working for some time in a project. One of the apps inside of it, 'my_app' has its models, views, forms, etc. working fine. It is included in `INSTALLED_APPS` as well.

Now I try to create a new file inside the `my_app` folder to write some logic but can't import the models. I tried:

```
from my_app.models import MyModel
```

But I get this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_app'`

Also tried this one as I was doing the imports in, for example, `views.py`:

```
from .models import MyModel
```

But this time I get this error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

These imports are working fine in other files in the same folder. Recently I deployed the app to Railway, maybe that has something to do with this error? Why suddenly this error happened?

**EDIT:**

`my_app/apps.py` file:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class My_appConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'my_app'
```

Also, recently started using Celery and my_project_folder/celery.py looks like this:

```
from celery import Celery 

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_project.settings')

app = Celery('my_project')
```

Comment: Share your apps.py from my_app.

Comment: Edited first post

Comment: does your my_app directory have an `__init__.py`?

Comment: yes it is blank but it does have it

Comment: depending on your django version the `__init__.py` file may need some contents. did you maybe upgrade your django version? ours defines a `default_app_config` variable for example.

Comment: I'm using Django 4.1.1. In a different project I'm using Django 3.2.1 and the same problem occurred, this time with django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings. error.